# C#, Win CE 4.2, Write file, power loss

Tags: c#, file, loss

I'm using C# & the compact framework on an embedded device to log data to a compact flash card. Because data integrity is of upper most importance, I'm wondering how to write the data to the flash disk. Will files get lost/damaged if power is lost during a write/flush or while the file is opened? What's the best way to do this?

By the way, the card uses FAT32 as file system if that's important.

greetings,
Korexio

Comment: it will depend to some extent on the actual hardware....

Comment: So which algorithm would you prefer?

1.) open - write - close for each data packet
or
2.) open - write - flush - write - flush - close

Or is it irrelevant because the files will get damaged either way (worst case)?

How can I find out how my hardware will handle the case of power loss while a file is written?

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, I personally would prefer to use the first method which is OPEN-WRITE-CLOSE. FAT32 is really vulnerable to data damage during write operation.